# Vue 3 Internal server error: v-model cannot be used on a prop, because local prop bindings are not writable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I found this error and blocked my webapps.

```
2:32:22 PM [vite] Internal server error: v-model cannot be used on a prop, because local prop bindings are not writable.
Use a v-bind binding combined with a v-on listener that emits update:x event instead.
  Plugin: vite:vue
  File: /Users/julapps/web/myapp/src/components/switch/AudienceTimerSlide.vue
```

I want to make timer data become data model (editable) and its default value from component props. Why this not work?  I'm very new in vuejs, how can i solve this problem? Kindly Please Help...

```
<template>
----
<div class="field-body">
    <div class="field">
        <div class="control">
            <input @keypress.enter="save" v-model="timer" type="number" class="input is-normal">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
-----
</template>

<script>

export default {

    props:['id', 'timer'],
    setup(props, context){
    
        -----
        
        const save = async() => {
            // save form
        }
    
        return {
            
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Props are read-only [One-Way Data Flow](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#one-way-data-flow)

Use an internal data property with `timer` as initial value. Like this:

```
data() {
    return {
       localTimer: timer 
    }
}
```

and

```
 <input @keypress.enter="save" v-model="localTimer" type="number" class="input is-normal">
```

---

Or replace `v-model` with `v-bind:value` & `emit` an event

```
@input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"
```

Like this:

```
 <input @keypress.enter="save" :value="timer" @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)" type="number" class="input is-normal">
```

Comment: how can i make changes from other components then it also changes this component value (timer)?

Comment: Added another option with using `timer` directly

Answer (score 15):

> you have to change  `defineProps(['question', 'choices'])`
> to
> `const props=defineProps(['question', 'choices'])`

> call as `props.question` in script  like
> `<TextInput :text="props.question" ></TextInput>`

Comment: That saved me hours, thank you.

Comment: This is answer #1; other answers may work but why go into extra complexity.

Answer (score 8):

```
v-model="timer"
```

Change to

```
:modelValue="timer"
@update:modelValue="timer = $event"
```

reference : https://learnvue.co/articles/v-model-guide

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with computed function:

```js
const emit = defineEmits(['update:timer']);
const newTimer = computed({
  get: () => props. timer,
  set: (newValue) => emit('update:timer', newValue),
});
```

and use it on your input:

`<input v-model="newTimer" @keypress.enter="save">`