# How to fix this error: "v-model cannot be used on a prop, because local prop bindings are not writable?"

Tags: vue.js, frontend, vue-component, vuejs3

I'm trying to make a dropdown sort and I get this error:

> VueCompilerError: v-model cannot be used on a prop, because local prop bindings are not writable. Use a v-bind binding combined with a v-on listener that emits update:x event instead.

[image: error photo]

Here are 2 components `App` and `MySelect`:

```html
<template>
  <!--  App Component -->
  <div class="app">
    <h1>Страница с постами</h1>
    <div class="app__btns">
      <my-button @click="showDialog">Cоздать пост</my-button>
      <my-select v-model="selectedSort" :options="sortOptions" />
    </div>
    <my-dialog v-model:show="dialogVisible">
      <post-form @create="createPost" />
    </my-dialog>
    <post-list :posts="posts" @remove="removePost" v-if="!isPostsLoading" />
    <div v-else>Идет загрузка...</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import PostForm from './components/PostForm.vue'
import PostList from './components/PostList.vue'
export default {
  components: { PostList, PostForm },
  data() {
    return {
      posts: [],
      dialogVisible: false,
      isPostsLoading: false,
      selectedSort: '',
      sortOptions: [
        { value: 'title', name: 'По названию' },
        { value: 'body', name: 'По содержанию' },
      ],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    createPost(post) {
      this.posts.push(post)
      this.dialogVisible = false
    },
    removePost(post) {
      this.posts = this.posts.filter((p) => p.id !== post.id)
    },
    showDialog() {
      this.dialogVisible = true
    },
    async fetchPosts() {
      try {
        this.isPostsLoading = true
        const res = await axios.get(
          'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_limit=10'
        )
        this.posts = res.data
      } catch (error) {
        alert('ошибка')
      } finally {
        this.isPostsLoading = false
      }
    },
  },

  mounted() {
    this.fetchPosts()
  },
}
</script>

<!-- флаг scoped - значит, что стили будут применяться только к этому комопненту -->
<style>
.app {
  padding: 20px;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.app__btns {
  margin: 15px 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
</style>
```

```html
<template>
  <!-- MySelect component -->
  <select v-model="modelValue" @change="changeOption">
    <option disabled value="">Выберите из списка</option>
    <option v-for="option in options" :key="option.value" :value="option.value">
      {{ option.name }}
    </option>
  </select>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'my-select',
  props: {
    modelValue: {
      type: String,
    },
    options: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => [],
    },
  },

  methods: {
    changeOption(event) {
      this.$emit('update:modelValue', event.target.value)
    },
  },
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped></style>
```

I need to update `modelValue`, so I tried to add

```
:value="modelValue"
```

instead of

```
v-model="modelValue"
```

and it works, but I'm not sure if this is the correct solution.

Comment: Here is an example of how to use v-model  for your own component: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue 3 Internal server error: v-model cannot be used on a prop, because local prop bindings are not writable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75123650/vue-3-internal-server-error-v-model-cannot-be-used-on-a-prop-because-local-pro)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If anyone else is encountering this issue when updating their vue version. Please note that this error started to appear on version 3.2.45.

For the implementation pattern, as noted on the documentation, props should be considered readonly within the component. Vue did not enforce it enough prior to version 3.2.45.

Documentation with links to good implementation patterns : https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#one-way-data-flow