# How can I bind value between parent and child component in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a component A，there is a dialog in this component A .I want to use `visible` property to control the visible of dialog.

Component A:

```js
<template>
    <dialog :visible="visibleProp"/>
</templage>
<script setup>
const visibleProp= ref(true)
<script>
```

Dialog:

```js
<template>
    <dialog  v-model="visible"></dialog>
</templage>
<script setup>
const prop = defineProps(['visible'])
<script>
```

note:dialog is another component.

I get this error

`v-model cannot be used on a prop, because local prop bindings are not writable.Use a v-bind binding combined with a v-on listener that emits update:x event instead.`
this is may caused by  `props should be considered readonly within the component.`

How can I change my code to achieve my goal？Thanks a lot!

Comment: then remove `v-model` somewhere. the error isn't related to your code

Comment: I have changed my question!thanks a lot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue 3 Internal server error: v-model cannot be used on a prop, because local prop bindings are not writable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75123650/vue-3-internal-server-error-v-model-cannot-be-used-on-a-prop-because-local-pro)

Answer (score 0):

[Vue3 SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Use `v-model` correctly - update it with a dedicated event. You can't change component props directly - they are read-only. In your case I suggest to name your `v-model` `visibility` to make it more explicitly. Refer to the Vue's documentation:

https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html

If you use a HTML native dialog you should watch your prop and call methods on the dialog's ref.
I strongly recommend to use the native HTML dialog due much better keyboard navigation and accessibility.

App.vue:

```
<script setup>

import MyDialog from './MyDialog.vue';
import {ref} from 'vue';
const visible = ref(false);

</script>
<template>
  <button @click="visible=true">Show dialog</button>
  <my-dialog v-model:visible="visible">
    <template #title>My Dialog</template>
    Testing v-model for the dialog's visibility
  </my-dialog>
</template>
```

MyDialog.vue

```
<script setup>

const props = defineProps({visible:Boolean});

import {ref, watch, onMounted} from 'vue';
const $dialog = ref();

onMounted(() => {
    watch(() => props.visible, val => val ? $dialog.value.showModal() : $dialog.value.close(), {immediate:true});
});

</script>
<template>
<dialog @close="$emit('update:visible', false)" ref="$dialog">
    <h2><slot name="title"></slot></h2>
    <p><slot></slot></p>
    <button @click="$dialog.close()">Close</button>
</dialog>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dialog

```
<template>
    <dialog  v-model="visible"></dialog>
</templage>
<script setup>
import { computed } from 'vue'
const prop = defineProps(['visible'])
const emits = defineEmits(['update:visible'])
const visible = computed({
  get() {
    return prop.visible
  },
  set(value) {
    emits('update:visible', value)
  }
})
</script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to intecept the update to visible from the dialog component and instead re-emit it for the parent component to handle, props should not be directly mutated.

Component A:

```
<template>
  <dialog v-model:visible="visibleProp" />
</template>
<script setup>
const visibleProp = ref(true);
</script>
```

Dialog:

```
<template>
  <dialog  :modelValue="visible" @update:modelValue="$emit('update:visible')"></dialog>
</templage>
<script setup>
const prop = defineProps(['visible'])
<script>
```

See https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html for more detail on custom v-models